# rememberPagerState not working, showing error in jetpack compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to implement a swipe feature in my section bar. If i swipe on the screen the section will change.

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.ExperimentalFoundationApi
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundat`your text`ion.pager.HorizontalPager
import androidx.compose.foundation.pager.rememberPagerState
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import andro`your text`idx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import com.example.capita.home.homeScreen.index.IndexScreen
import com.example.capita.home.homeScreen.overview.OverviewScreen
import com.example.capita.home.homeScreen.sectionBar.homeSectionBar
import com.example.capita.home.homeScreen.stocks.StockScreen

@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun HomeScreen() {
    val sections = listOf("Overview", "Indices", "Stocks")
    val pagerState = rememberPagerState(pageCount = sections.size)

    Column {
        homeSectionBar(
            homeSelectedSection = sections[pagerState.currentPage],
            onSectionSelected = { section ->
                pagerState.animateScrollToPage(sections.indexOf(section))
            },
        )

        HorizontalPager(state = pagerState) { page ->
            when (sections[page]) {
                "Overview" -> OverviewScreen()
                "Indices" -> IndexScreen()
                "Stocks" -> StockScreen()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

getting error on rememberPagerState
None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.
rememberPagerState(Int = ..., Float = ...) defined in androidx.compose.foundation.pager
rememberPagerState(Int = ..., Float = ..., () → Int) defined in androidx.compose.foundation.pager

help me out please

no idea what to do as this was the only thing i managed to come about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!!
It works well after upgrading accompanist version to `0.27.1`

```
implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-pager:0.27.1"
```

Repository: https://google.github.io/accompanist/pager/

Answer (score 9):

Check which version of Compose you are using, since version 1.5.0-alpha04 and up, the pageCount parameter has moved to `PagerState`.

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-foundation#1.5.0-alpha04

With the latest version of Compose, you would do the following:

```kotlin
val state = rememberPagerState { 10 }
HorizontalPager(
  state = state,
  modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
) { page ->
  // page count
}
```

Previous versions of Compose pager allowed for specifying the page count on the composable:

```kotlin
HorizontalPager(pageCount = 4) {
  // your content
}
```

This is to allow for querying of the number of pages from the `PagerState` object.

The change can be seen here: https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/2535728

Comment: Hey @riggaroo what was the reason for making page count in rememberPagerState a function rather than just an int?

Comment: @alfietap this was to support getting the number of pages from the state instead of needing to keep track of the number of pages yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way.

```
 val pagerState = rememberPagerState(initialPage = 0)
 HorizontalPager(pageCount = pages.size, state = pagerState) {}
```