# HorizontalPager in JetpackCompose does not work

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

```
val pagerState = rememberPagerState(initialPage = 0,
        initialPageOffsetFraction = 0f, pageCount = {
        4
    })
```

Cannot find a parameter with this name: pageCount

Maybe I used the wrong version of compose somewhere. but HorizontalPager does not have a pageCount parameter, although everything is present in the documentation. Check this https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/pager#add-page

My properties gradle

```
buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.4"
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76668792/14162959